# Lazy-loading Custom UIScrollView with dynamic grid size?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

So I wrote a custom subclass of UIScrollView that basically displays rectangles in a 2-column grid, but while the width of each is fixed to half the width of the iPhone/iPad screen, the height varies, depending on the dimensions of the picture within it. All's well and good now, but I can imagine that after adding lots of these subviews to my UIScrollView subclass, things are going to lag. So I'm trying to implement lazy loading analogous to UITableView's dequeueing reusable cell method.

[image]

I've looked at a handful of other questions on SO, but they all involve paging based on full-screen photos, including Apple's WWDDC PhotoScroller example.

Anyone have any insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to keep track of the views that are scrolled off screen and reuse them.

You might want to check out [ATArrayView](https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS).  It implements a recycling mechanism like what the UITableView has except with a UIScrollView with an arbitrary number of rows and columns?

I've used it as the basis for my own image scrolling code and is pretty good.  It's delegate methods follow the spirit of UITableView data source and delegate protocols.

Good luck

Tim